# Zuora Authentication Issue #code 90000011

Tags: zuora

When I call 'https://apisandbox-api.zuora.com/rest/v1/accounts' with required apiAccessKeyId, apiSecretAccessKey and parameters, I recieve the response

```
{
  "success": false,
  "reasons": [
    {
      "code": 90000011,
      "message": "this resource is protected, please sign in first"
    }
  ]
}
```

Not clear what is exact issue.

Answer (score 2):

You need to call the connection api first in order to access any object in the Zuora sandbox.

Request URL
GET: https://apisandbox-api.zuora.com/rest/v1/connections

and the response you would see:

{
  "success": true
}

Give it a try after calling this Api. It should be resolved then.Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You need to sign in first, there is an example in the Zuora SDK using a ConnectionManager [source](https://github.com/zuora/rest-java-client/blob/master/src/main/java/com/zuora/sdk/samples/ConnectionManager.java) :

```
final ZClient Z_CLIENT = new ZClient();
final ConnectionManager cm = new ConnectionManager();
if (!cm.isConnected(Z_CLIENT, (String) ZConfig.getInstance().getVal("default.tenant.user.id"),
    (String) ZConfig.getInstance().getVal("default.tenant.password")))
{
throw new RuntimeException("Couln't open a connection to Zuora API !");
}
```